# Bipartition and coloring

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I am having hard time solving the following problem:

> Let $k$ be a positive integer. Then for every $2^k$ colorable graph $G=(V,E)$ we have $E=E_1 \cup \ldots \cup E_k$ and $\forall 1 \leq i \leq k \ : \ (V,E_i)$ is bipartite.

I thought about looking at the $2^k$ partition of $E$ according to some $2^k$ valid coloring , and then tring to build from them the "k-bipartitioning" , but I had no success doing so.

I will be happy for some clues about what to do.

Comment: Clue: you may take inspiration from the [poisoned wine puzzle](http://www.mindcipher.com/puzzles/121).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each vertex has a colour which is a length-$k$ binary number.  For any edge, these two binary numbers differ in at least one digit.  How can you sort these edges into $k$ different groups?

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I got confused in my first proof :(